# Defining Your Own Functions with a few procedures in Wolfram Language

Tags: function, stored-procedures, wolfram-mathematica, procedural-programming, wolfram-language

I have created a function with one procedure....

```
    Func1[n_] := Table[a[i], {i, n}]
```

which returns

```
     Func1[5]
     {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]}
```

I also have created a function with a few parameters or with a few arguments, few variables!

```
    Func1[x_, y_, z_] := (x + y)*z - 1
```

which returns

```
    Func1[5, 2, 3]
    20
```

But what about if I want to create a function with a several procedure which returns whatever I want?
I already know that when one procedure is done I have to type " ; " at the end of this procedure!
Like in for loops we do....

```
   For[k = 2, k < 3, k++,
       S := Table[a[i], {i, n}];
       B := Dimensions[S][[1]]];
      ]
```

So I need to create a function with a several procedure!
How to do it?
Please help me!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's ontopic on Mathematica.SE

Answer (score 1):

A couple of examples here.  Remember to use lower-case initial letters to avoid conflicting with built-in functions which all start with a capital letter.

```
s[n_] := Table[a[i], {i, n}]

b[s_] := Dimensions[s][[1]]

For[k = 2, k < 3, k++,
 x = s[k];
 Print[b[x]]]
```

> 2

```
For[k = 2, k < 3, k++,
 Print[b[s[k]]]]
```

> 2

Answer (score 0):

Use [parentheses for grouping](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html).
For example

```
set$s$b[n_Integer] := ($s = Table[a[i], {i, n}];
                       $b = Dimensions[$s][[1]];)
```

Now, after executing, e.g.,

```
set$s$b[5]
```

one will get

```
$s
```

> `{a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]}`

```
$b
```

> `5`

However, making use of [modularity](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThingsOverview.html) might be a better design choice in situations where the execution of several procedures is needed.